# How can I define a global cell style in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel

It is pretty straightforward to create new cell styles in Excel 2010. My problem is that the new style I create is only available for that spreadsheet.

How can I create a global cell style that will be there with the Excel default styles each time I create a new spreadsheet? Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

The Styles object is a member of Workbook not Application. There is no way AFAIK to add a style to the built-in collection (the BuiltIn property is readonly). 
 But you could make a style you create available to new workbooks by including your new styles in a workbook template.
 To modify the default template start with a blank workbook, create the styles you want, then save the workbook in your XLSTART directory as a template called Book.XLTX or Book.XLT

Comment: Then you run the risk of messing up the original template.... any way to choose from several templates?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the help on this from MS.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-cell-styles-to-use-in-all-new-workbooks-0b3905c5-45d0-4ad4-be39-571f445d30cb

Here's the tutorial in full in case that link goes down.
[image]